# Show info screen & set passcode screen once iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, passwords

Newbie here in terms of developing and the site.

Basically I want to design an app, that shows the splash screen (which I've managed to do), then show an info screen telling users to set passcode to access app and then finally asking users to set the 4 digit passcode and then everytime the app is opened after that it asks for the users pass code.

So the question is how to do that?

I'm probably asking for a lot but if you guys could direct me that would be great :)

Comment: Add a "login" ViewController as your initial ViewController in Storyboard.

Comment: @Larme I have a ViewController set up

Answer (score 1):

To make this app you need to use `NSUserDefaults`. The simplest way is to create a bool variable that you make to tell the app, that password has been already set, or if not send it to another viewController to set it.

**Storing Value on NSUserDefaults**

When the user finishes setting his first password and confirms it, save the value on `NSUserDefaults` with key **AppUsageCheck**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"AppUsageCheck"];
```

**Reading value back**

```
//On application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
//If this value exists, check it if the user has set his password
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppUsageCheck"])
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AppUsageCheck"]==YES) {
        //User has set it already, so go and show the user to enter his password
    }
    else
    {
        //User has to set the password, because he doesn't have one
    }
}
else
{
    //User has to set the password, because he doesn't have one
}
```